# copy values from one table to another with WHERE

Tags: mysql

I have two tables and I want to add info from one table to another, but tables have equal rows.

```
INSERT INTO wp_posts ( 
      id, 
      post_author, 
      post_content, 
      post_title,
      post_name,
      post_type
            ) 
SELECT  id, 
      3, 
      post_content, 
      post_title,
      post_name,
      post_type
FROM wp_posts2
WHERE  post_type='Vacancy'
```

So I get error

```
[Err] 1062 - Duplicate entry '7142' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

How can I add only new rows?

Comment: What do you want to happen to the duplicate rows? Do you want to keep the old contents, or replace it with the new contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get only new IDs:

```
INSERT INTO wp_posts ( 
      id, 
      post_author, 
      post_content, 
      post_title,
      post_name,
      post_type
            ) 
SELECT  id, 
      3, 
      post_content, 
      post_title,
      post_name,
      post_type
FROM wp_posts2
WHERE  post_type='Vacancy'
and id not in (select id from wp_posts)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that in the table wp_posts id is the primary key and wp_posts2 has same value(s) for id. That's why it is throwing error.

If id is the AUTO_INCREMENT field then you should not need to include 'id' in the query as follows:

```
INSERT INTO wp_posts ( 
  post_author, 
  post_content, 
  post_title,
  post_name,
  post_type
        ) 
SELECT 
  3, 
  post_content, 
  post_title,
  post_name,
  post_type
FROM wp_posts2
WHERE  post_type='Vacancy'
```